# Path of "New Item + Edit" class

Tags: list, 2013, css, branding

The class of New Item is "ms-list-addnew-imgSpan20" but can't find the location of the css file. I looked into the corev3.css but it wasn't there. Does anyone know where it is?

Comment: Are you asking about SP 2007 or 2010 ?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is part of any external CSS file it'll be in corev15.css. But it could also be that the CSS is pushed inline as on many occasions with SharePoint 2013 (sadly).

Answer (score 2):

Even if you find out where it is in the built in sharepoint css files, you shouldn't ever go and overwrite it. The reason for this is simple. When you do upgrades, patches, etc. Your changes might be overriden. This is why you should place your own css file using the http://tommdaly.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/sharepoint-cssregistration-or-link/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IE to view the page you can use the [Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find the item and [trace the style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699337%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to a specific location. There are also equivalents in FF and Chrome but this will at least get you a start on where the style is defined.

Comment: Yes, I looked with the Dev Tools.